# database query not working properly laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a database query as below:

```
$data = DB::table('settings')->select('value')->where('name', '=', $name)->get();
        echo $data["value"];
```

but it gives error:

> Undefined index: value

if I `echo $data`; then I get below result:

```
[{"value":"theme_default"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` returns a [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) object, which has magic methods to turn itself into a string when you try to use it as such (like with an `echo` statement). As you can see in the JSON that you've printed, `$data` is an array or collection of objects, so you want the first one in the collection before trying to get the value:

```
$row = $data->first();
echo $row->value;
```

Comment: oh now I understand. but ``echo $row->value`` worked echo $row['value'] gives me error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = DB::table('settings')->select('value')->where('name', '=', $name)->first();
echo $data["value"]; 
//or
echo $data->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the result into an array like this:

```
$data = DB::table('settings')
            ->select('value')
            ->where('name', '=', $name)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
//then use the value of the first element
dd(@$data[0]['value']);
```

, but I strongly suggest that you use the [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) in order to make use of its powerful methods.